# How do I remove .php extension from the website url using .htaccess, or another way

Tags: php, web, web-applications, server

I need to remove .php extension from my website url. I tried lots of code, but cant do it. I used .htaccess in following way:

#remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
enter code hereRewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Try with this code and see is it work